# Can I set color fields by hex value

Tags: fieldtypes

Can I set the value of a [Color Field](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/color-fields) to a hex value? Or only if the particular browser's color picker supports this? Maybe this is a feature request: please let us get and set color values in hex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have created a Color Field the color selector dialogue uses your browsers built-in color selector.

On Chrome and Firefox, you should see a dialogue like this:

| [image]  | [image] |

If you click over to the 2nd tab (indicated by the sliders) you'll be able to insert a `hex` value for the color in the input field at the bottom.

In Firefox you'll need to select RGB Sliders from the dropdown, then you'll see the Hex color input at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: So Chrome and Safari: yes, Firefox: no? I hadn't found that in Chrome, so thanks!!

Comment: I added a screenshot for Firefox. The Hex input is there, just a bit hidden.

Comment: For what it's worth, the native color picker that Craft activates in Windows 7 (in Chrome) is the same fugly one in use since Windows 95: http://i.stack.imgur.com/awjVW.png - I'd urge integration of a Javascript-based custom color picker.